# Using eclipse and bitbucket with the .p2 libraries causing issues

Tags: eclipse, repository, bitbucket, libraries, eclipse-classpath

We are a group of Uni students who have to develop a java application using eclipse. We use Bitbucket, as they offer free private repositories to students (We are using GitKraken to interact with the repository).

The other students cannot use the application as there is a problem with the /Users/whatever/.p2 libraries. It still refers to my username in their project and won't change the path. What do I do in this case?

Do I go change the path somehow? Because after a lot of googling I am still confused about changing that path.

I don't want to use eclipse's, built-in (if that's the correct term), features to interact with the repository and not use GitKraken? The thing is the other students only know how to use GitKraken and I don't have time to teach them. (They aren't really interested in using the "eclipse method" and want to stick to GitKraken)

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: _"...as there is a problem..."_ Which problem (please give a step-by-step instruction to reproduce this issue and show us a screenshot of the result)? _"It still refers..."_ What do you mean with _it_?

Comment: It was a class not found error. Finally figured out how to set that. The main issue is really that I do not really see how I can use my eclipse project with the repository. I figured out how to use a Visual Studio project in a repository in which everyone can work. But Eclipse has issues with our repository such as the library (for SWT application windows such as org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core) paths being invalid